# Value is not updating when inside `setInterval()`

Tags: reactjs

```
const [value, setValue] = useState<string | undefined>("");

  useEffect(() => {
    let i = 0;
    const valueInterval = setInterval(() => {
      setValue(oldValue => {
        if (oldValue === INTRO_TEXT) {
          clearInterval(valueInterval);
          return value;
        }
        console.warn(oldValue)
        return oldValue ? oldValue + INTRO_TEXT.charAt(i) + "" : "";
      });
      i++;
    }, 100);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(valueInterval);
    };
  }, [value]);
```

I'd like to append a character one by one until I get it equal to `INTRO_TEXT`, but the `oldValue` seems to be always `undefined`, i.e. it's not updating state as I would like it to. What am I doing wrong inside `setInterval` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You have added `value` as a dependecy to `useEffect`, so setting that state would re-render the component and reset the whole thing.
2. "" is also a falsy value, so having a conditional operator on it always gets you "" back.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;
const { render } = ReactDOM;

const INTRO_TEXT = 'Welcome to Stackoverflow';

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    let i = 0;
    const valueInterval = setInterval(() => {
      setValue(oldValue => {
        if (oldValue === INTRO_TEXT) {
          clearInterval(valueInterval);
          return oldValue;
        }
        console.warn(oldValue)
        return oldValue + INTRO_TEXT.charAt(i);
      });
      i++;
    }, 100);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(valueInterval);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <p>{value}</p>
  )
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const [value, setValue] = useState<string | undefined>("");
const [displayedValue, setDisplayedValue] = useState<string | undefined>("");

useEffect(() => {
  clearInterval(window.myInterval);
  let i = 0 
  const valueArr = value.split('')
  window.myInterval = setInterval(() => {
    const newVal = displayedValue + valueArr[i]
    setDisplayedValue(newVal)
    i++
  }, 100);
}, [value]);
```